# Why did Feynman tell "we cannot locate earth's angular position, but we can tell that it is changing"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, galilean-relativity

I was reading "Symmetry in physics" by Feynman, where he wrote:

> If we perform sufficiently delicate experiments, we can tell that the earth **is rotating**, but not that it **had rotated**. In other words, we cannot locate its angular position, but we can tell that it is changing."

What does Feynman want to mean here? Why can't we measure angular position, but measure that it is changing? Why can't we tell that earth **had rotated**, but tell that earth **is rotating**?

Comment: He meant that physics is invariant under a global rotation of co-ordinates, but even a uniform rotation would be detectable - *e.g.* through Newton's bucket and its GTR equivalents (accelerometers on a frame of nonzero extent that will tell us whether the frame is being Lie-dragged as it moves through time, Lense Thirring effect and so forth). We can of course make observations of different objects and check whether we have rotated relative to them. I'm guessing he means that we can't really rule out that these distant objects hadn't decided to up and shift together to produce an apparent ....

Comment: ... rotation when there was indeed none - this comes down to an Occam's razor approach - we'd have to explain how these things could move faster than light to produce the relative apparent rotation.